# Comparing row values from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, syntax

I am trying to generate a query.
I need the values from column TABLEOBJECTID from the below table where
TABLENAME = 'EMPLOYEE' and INTERFACE MAINTAINED (CUSTFIELDNAME) = YES (CUSTFIELDVALUE) and 
TRANSFER FLAG (CUSTFIELDNAME) = YES (CUSTFIELDVALUE)
Any help is appreciated. The SQL shown below isnt working and gets data but it gets values from other fields as well.

Data:

```
TABLEOBJECTID CUSTFIELDID TABLENAME CUSTFIELDNAME           CUSFIELDVALUE
2                    4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    No
2                    5    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER HOURS TO AG    Yes
2                    7    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER FLAG           Yes
3                    4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    Yes
3                    7    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER FLAG           Yes
31                   4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    No
31                   5    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER HOURS TO AG    No
31                   6    EMPLOYEE  DEFAULT JOB CODE    
94                   4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    No
94                   6    EMPLOYEE  DEFAULT JOB CODE        0325
94                   7    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER FLAG           No
96                   4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    No
96                   6    EMPLOYEE  DEFAULT JOB CODE        0325
100                  4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    No
100                  5    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER HOURS TO AG    No
100                  6    EMPLOYEE  DEFAULT JOB CODE    
100                  7    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER FLAG           No
101                  4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    Yes
101                  6    EMPLOYEE  DEFAULT CODE            9760
101                  7    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER FLAG           Yes
```

Expected Result:

```
TABLEOBJECTID CUSTFIELDID TABLENAME CUSTFIELDNAME           CUSFIELDVALUE
3                    4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    Yes
3                    7    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER FLAG           Yes
101                  4    EMPLOYEE  INTERFACE MAINTAINED    Yes   
101                  7    EMPLOYEE  TRANSFER FLAG           Yes
```

I have been trying this script but it bring results from other CUSTFIELDNAME too:

```
select CWA.TABLEOBJECTID ,CWA.CUSTFIELDID ,CWA.CUSTFIELDNAME ,CWA.CUSTFIELDVALUE ,CWA.TABLENAME ,CWA.TABLEOBJECTID  from az.CWCUSTFIELD CWA 
    inner join  az.CWCUSTFIELD CWB on CWA.TABLEOBJECTID  =CWB.TABLEOBJECTID  and CWA.CUSTFIELDID <> CWB.CUSTFIELDID 
    where  CWA.tablename = 'EMPLOYEE' and CWB.TABLENAME ='EMPLOYEE' and (CWA.CUSTFIELDVALUE = 'YES' and CWB.CUSTFIELDVALUE = 'YES')
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. 'TABLEOBJECTID' is a repeating value in the data you posted, is there a column that uniquely identifies each record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the filter on CUSTFIELDID as you are looking for only INTERFACE MAINTAINED (4) and TRANSFER FLAG(7) so you should add filters on this field for both tables.

```
AND CWA.CUSTFIELDID(4,7) AND CWB.CUSTFIELDID(4,7)
```

OR You can apply filter on CUSTFIELDNAME instead of CUSTFIELDID, like

```
AND CWA.CUSTFIELDNAME IN ('INTERFACE MAINTAINED', 'TRANSFER FLAG')
   AND CWB.CUSTFIELDNAME IN ('INTERFACE MAINTAINED', 'TRANSFER FLAG')
```

The final query -

```
select CWA.TABLEOBJECTID ,
  CWA.CUSTFIELDID ,
  CWA.CUSTFIELDNAME ,
  CWA.CUSTFIELDVALUE ,
  CWA.TABLENAME ,
  CWA.TABLEOBJECTID  
from az.CWCUSTFIELD CWA 
inner join  az.CWCUSTFIELD CWB on CWA.TABLEOBJECTID  =CWB.TABLEOBJECTID  
            and CWA.CUSTFIELDID <> CWB.CUSTFIELDID 
where  CWA.tablename = 'EMPLOYEE' 
  and CWB.TABLENAME ='EMPLOYEE' 
  and CWA.CUSTFIELDVALUE = 'YES' 
  and CWB.CUSTFIELDVALUE = 'YES'
  and CWA.CUSTFIELDNAME IN ('INTERFACE MAINTAINED', 'TRANSFER FLAG')
  and CWB.CUSTFIELDNAME IN ('INTERFACE MAINTAINED', 'TRANSFER FLAG')
```

Comment: Hi Vinit, Thanks for your response. the only issue with your suggestion is I wont be knowing or dont want to hardcode the values 4,7. because once I deploy this in other systems it may very well have different ID's.     CWA.CUSTFIELDID(4,7) AND CWB.CUSTFIELDID(4,7)

Comment: then You can apply filter on CUSTFIELDNAME, like 
   `AND CWA.CUSTFIELDNAME IN ('INTERFACE MAINTAINED', 'TRANSFER FLAG')
   AND CWB.CUSTFIELDNAME IN ('INTERFACE MAINTAINED', 'TRANSFER FLAG')`

Comment: Your Awesome....It worked like Charm. I always wondered how to get such skills. Anyway. Thanks very much